# Replace some char within a string (XML format)

Tags: c#, xml

I was given with a String variable with the following content:

```
<main>
<Title title="Hello World" />
<Content content="bla bla bla... by <1% to ??? on other bla bla...." />
</main>
```

This string will eventually passed to a Stored Procedure for XQuery.

As you can see, the content of "Content" contains of char **"<"** , which when I try to parse in Stored Procedure, it return with an error.

My question is how to convert the **"<"** into **&lt ;** (in this case **<1%** to **&lt ;1%**) in an efficient way.

I want to retain other **"<"** as it is.

Tks

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a valid XML.

Comment: `<Content="foo" />` is not valid XML at all as there are no anonymous attributes. Did you mean `<Content>foo</Content>` instead?

Comment: hi there, I have updated the original codes... it should be as <Content content="bla bla bla... by <1% to ??? on other bla bla...." />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you updated your question to point out you are dealing with XML, but the unencoded values are in attribute values, not `#text` nodes, then it makes it somewhat simpler, just extract the attribute value using a similar approach to my previous answer, then use a library function to entitize it, then output.

Note that CDATA only applies to `#text`, not attributes.

```
String doc =
@"<main>
<Title title=""Hello World"" />
<Content content=""bla bla bla... by <1% to ??? on other bla bla...."" />
</main>";

Int32 contentOpenStart = doc.IndexOf("<Content");
Int32 contentAttribContentValueStart = doc.IndexOf("content=\"", contentOpenStart) + "content=\"".Length;
Int32 contentAttibContentValueEnd    = doc.IndexOf("\"", contentAttribContentValueStart);

String attributeValueOld = doc.Substring( contentAttribContentValueStart, contentAttibContentValueEnd );
String attributeValueNew = System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlEncode( attributeValueOld );

String doc2 = String.Concat(
    doc.Substring( 0, contentAttribContentValueStart );
    attributeValueNew,
    doc.Substring( contentAttibContentValueEnd );
);
```

`doc2` then contains the fixed attribute value.

Note that using `HtmlEncode` to perform HTML-Encoding of entities is not strictly correct in XML, as the set of XML entities is much smaller than HTML's - indeed, XML is only concerned with `&amp;`, `&gt;`, `&lt;`, `&quot;` and `&apos;`, all other values should be in the document as raw/native characters.

Comment: Good idea for your proposed solution, I managed to construct a solution by minor adjusting your codes.

Answer (score 0):

(This answer is based on the assumption you're dealing with structurally correct XML, just with unencoded entities in `#text` nodes - this answer does not apply if your input data really does look like `<Title="foo" />` - which isn't XML at all)

If I understand your problem correctly, you have an XML document in a `String` instance which contains improperly escaped/entitized special characters, which prevents you from using a normal XML parser to read the document.

If you're dealing with an XML-compliant system, then you can use `<![DATA[` and then not need to attempt to process the content of the `<Content>` element, the trick then becomes inserting the CDATA delimiters.

While it's often said one cannot use a regular-expression to parse XML (as XML is not a [Regular Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)), you can take advantage of the grammatical rules of XML to extract and identify tags.

So if you have this:

```
<Content someAttribute="someValue">
reduce sales by <1% in order to ensure that profit > loss
</Content>
```

Then you can do this:

```
String doc = @"<main><Title...";
Int32 contentOpenStart = doc.IndexOf("<Content");
Int32 contentOpenEnd   = doc.IndexOf(">", contentOpenStart);

Int32 contentCloseStart = doc.IndexOf("</Content>", contentOpenEnd);
```

This code then tells us the locatations of the angle-brackets of the `<Content>` element's two tags, with which we can insert the CDATA delimiters:

```
String newDocument = String.Concat(
    doc.Substring( 0, contentOpenEnd + 1 ), // "<main>...<Content...>"
    "<![CDATA[",
    doc.Substring( contentOpenEnd + 1, contentCloseStart ),
    "]]>",
    doc.Substring( contentCloseStart ) "</Content>..."
);
```

`newDocument` will then be this:

```
<Content someAttribute="someValue"><![CDATA[
reduce sales by <1% in order to ensure that profit > loss
]]></Content>
```

...which is valid XML.

Comment: hi @Dai, tks for the comment. the issue is that the value is within the attribute of the tag, not in its content. so, instead of having: <Content someAttribute="someValue">reduce sales by <1% in order to ensure that profit > loss</Content>, i got: <Content someAttribute="reduce sales by <1% in order to ensure that profit > loss" /> how can i adjust the codes accordingly? can we use CDATA for attribute as well?